# Как поменять текст кнопки при наведении на нее курсора средствами css или javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как поменять текст кнопки `button` при наведении на нее курсора средствами `css` или `javascript`?

Comment: А причем тут текст находящийся в кнопке?

Comment: на константный текст или он может быть разный? например при наведении всегда чтоб было написано "Купить". Опишите вопрос обширнее

Comment: при наведении будет всегда один и тот же текст

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Текст будет изменяться при наведении (CSS):

```css
button::before {
  content: attr(text);
}

button:hover::before {
  content: attr(hover-text);
}
```

```html
<button text="DEFAULT TEXT" hover-text="NEW TEXT FROM ATTRIBUTE">
</button>
```

Без использования функции [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/attr()):

```css
button::before {
  content: "DEFAULT TEXT";
}

button:hover::before {
  content: "TEXT WHEN HOVER";
}
```

```html
<button>
</button>
```

Comment: жаль, нельзя два плюса поставить ))

Comment: Эх, надо было первый ответ тоже оставить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я думаю, так удобнее (не надо лезть в разные файлы). Но я могу вернуть его, если Вы считаете, что он необходим :D

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов думаю стоит, вторым вариантом добавить тоже. Пусть будет

Answer (score 2):

Средствами JS. Способов много предложу такой.

```js
btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  this.value = "Updated";
})

btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  this.value = "Old Text";
})
```

```html
 <input id="btn" type="button" value="Old Text">
```

Comment: в общем случае лучше брать новый текст из дата-атрибута, например.

Comment: @teran Как указал способов много. Предложил один